# Как на layout повесить OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, setonclicklistener

Есть LinerLayout в фрагменте. Нужно на него повесить OnClickListener, но появляется ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Как это сделать? (LinerLayout находится в toolbar)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_user_profile, container, false);

    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    LinearLayout layout1=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_toolbar_view);
    layout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment someFragment = new ProfileFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame2, someFragment ); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

разметка:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.asus.testapp147.SearchFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorBlue">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chat_toolbar_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable = "true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:focusable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/chat_user_avatar"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:src="@drawable/a_avator"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/name_user"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/online"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: вроде также, как и с остальными view или viewgroup. mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... }

Comment: @YungBlade, ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: @3Jlou4uTep Возможно, что вы присвоили `LinearLayout`  недействительный идентификатор.

Comment: Я сейчас попробую угадать... ТС ищет в активити через findViewById лейаут, который находится во фрагменте. @3Jlou4uTep, так?

Comment: @eugeneek, нет, layout находится во фрагменте и при нажатии на него должен открыться другой фргамент

Comment: @pavlofff, добавил код и разметку